# Dompdf надо вывести генерируемую картинку

Tags: php, dompdf

```
MySite/index.php/Welcome/printBarcode/001
```

Здравствуйте у меня тут генерируемая картинка при переходе на эту страницу последние числа преобразовывается в картинку с штрих кодом

этот файл не сохраняется и поэтому если подставить .png то выйдет ошибка из за отсутствия файла

а Dompdf без формата не принимает, но если поставить отдельный тег (извне Dompdf) в  то все выводится корректно

пробовал file_get_contents но тут нужна авторизация и при написании полной пути оно выводит login_page

php7.3, dompdf-v0.83

Comment: Забавный вопрос... так и вертится на языке, что надо как то "подправить" URL, в момент "скармливания" её dompdf. Но как без тяжелой артилерии типа nginx или urlrewrite это сделать - не могу придумать...

Comment: А так вопрос смог обьяснить?

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предложить такое "кривенькое" решение:

1. Как я понял вопрос: я так понял, что у Вас есть ID = 001759969001, Вам нужно "скормить" его скрипту printBarcode, (который, как я понимаю, представляет собой папку в файловой системе сервера, на коотором запущен php). Результатом будет картирка, которую выдаст printBarcode. Эту картинку надо передать в dompdf, который из картинки сделает pdf- файл. Но из за того, что dompdf требует "картирку с расширением" - сдлелать этот шаг - переход от сгенерированной картинки к генерации pdf - не получается.
2. Как я предлагаю решить проблему: давайте напишем промежуточный скрипт. Этот скрипт будет лежать в отдельной папке и представлять из себя простой php - файл. Он будет получать ID, переданный ему GET-ом, то есть обращение к скрипту будет выглядеть как MySite/script.php?ID=001759969001
   Скрипт делает буквально вот что: он извлекает ID (при помощи $id = $_GET['id'];), обращается по пути MySite/index.php/Welcome/printBarcode/001759969001 при помощи file_get_contents(), сохраняет полученный файл во временную директорию с расширением png, а потом путь к этому - только что записанному на диск - файлу передаёт в dompdf.

Как я понял, Вы пытались сделать нечто подобное.

Так как у меня нет полной картины - я не собо понимаю, в каком месте и почему там возникнет авторизация. Мне кажется - так как авторизацией управляете Вы изнутри скрипта - можно написать его так, что никакой дополнительной авторизации не понадобится.

Если я что то не так понял - попробуйте написать в комментариях или дополнить вопрос, вполне возможно, найдутся более опытные товарищи, которые еще что то посоветуют

Comment: Нашел другой способ. 

В функционалах Barcode было где можно указать имя файла, в этом случае он сохраняет файл.

Я сделал клон функции который нужно отправить в атрибутах переменную с кодом, 

потом когда оно сохранялась подставил как обычную картинку с форматом и после всех операции удаляю картинку

Comment: @ElamanKaljan - кросавчег, как пишут в этих самых интернетах! Главное - что решил проблему!

Answer (score 0):

Решал подобную задачу так:

Библиотека, которую мы использовали для генерации штрих-кода, умела возвращать содержимое картинки без сохранения в файл.

В коде контроллера было примерно такое:

```php
$barcode = $this->barcodeGenerator->createPng('908');
$html = $this->render->render('pdf_doc.tpl', ['barcode' => base64_encode($barcode)]);
$pdf = $this->pdf->createFromHtml($html);
return $pdf;
```

В шаблоне для PDF было что-то такое:

```php
<img src='data:image/png;base64,{{ barcode }}'>
```

И всё работало хорошо, без насилия файловой системы